# find all INS, text node wrap into the INS tag and find del with new DEL TAG respective class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<body>
    <div class="para">
        <ins>A computer is a</ins> popular <del>new</del><ins> device</ins>
    </div>

    <div class="para">
        <ins>Stored programs</ins><del>required the re-wiring and re-structuring of the machine.</del>
    </div>
    <div class="para">
        <ins>Integrated </ins>new<del>circuits</del><ins>System </ins>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to grab all the ins, and the text node for the respective para class and wrap into the new ins tag and also del tag to new del tag like the following

```
<html> 
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="para">
        <ins>A computer is a popular</ins><del>new</del><ins> device</ins>
    </div>

    <div class="para">
        <ins>Stored programs</ins><del>required the re-wiring and re-structuring of the machine.</del>
    </div>
    <div class="para">
        <ins>Integrated new</ins><del>circuits</del><ins>System </ins>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried the following code

```
var unit = $('.para');
$.each(unit, function(){
   var nodes = $(this).find('ins');
})
```

help me resolve this

Comment: Why is `"popluar"` not at `html` at expected result? Also, first `.para` at result is either missing beginning `<ins>` or has extra `</ins>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.each()`, `.contents()`, `.filter()` to get `#text` nodes within `.para` elements that have `.parentElement` equal to current `.para` element; `.appendTo()` to append the selected `#text` nodes to first `ins` element within current `.para` element

```js
$(".para").each(function(index, element) {
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeName === "#text" && this.parentElement === element
  }).appendTo($("ins:first", element))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="para">
    <ins>A computer is a</ins> popular <del>new</del><ins> device </ins>
  </div>

  <div class="para">
    <ins>Stored programs</ins><del>required the re-wiring and re-structuring of the machine.</del>
  </div>
  <div class="para">
    <ins>Integrated </ins>new<del>circuits</del><ins>System </ins>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `document.querySelectorAll('.para')` to get an array of them. And then loop through them targeting their children.

It's not jquery though, not sure if you're dead set on using jquery or are happy with some vanilla.